# Simulating a specific MOSFET circuit in PSPICE

Tags: mosfet, pspice, inverting-amplifier

I want to simulate this circuit in **PSPICE** (to get approximate output waveform (\$v_o\$))

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwraAY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, \$v_{in}=0.2 \sin(wt) , \$
& NMOS specifications:  \$ \mu_n C_{ox}(\frac{W}{L})=2mA/V^2 \, , \, V_T=1V\$
Also here MOS is acting as an amplifier [Given]

so,
My equivalent circuit in PSPICE is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1QNkH.png)</sup>

and the corresponding **.CIR code** is as follows:
Vin 1 0 SIN(0 0.2 10K)
R1 1 2 1k
C1 2 3 1u
R2 3 0 1MEG
M1 4 3 5 5 my-mos L=1u W=1u
.MODEL my-mos NMOS (VTO=1V Kp=2m lambda=0 Level=5)
R3 6 4 7k
Vccp 6 0 DC 12V
C2 5 0 1u
Ibias 5 7 DC 1mA
Vccn 7 0 DC -12V
.tran 1us 200us
.probe V(Vin) V(4,0)
.end

Actual waveform should be like this:
[image]

But the simulated code is giving wrong results
It is showing V(4,0) or \$ v_o  = 5 - 1.4\sin(2 \pi (10k) t ) \$
i.e
[image] 
Here, answer should be V(4,0)= \$ 5 - 2.8 \sin(2  \pi (10k) t \$ ).

so,have i missed any coding lines, or a better model of MOSFET can be used for this circuit problem;any suggestions please...

Comment: In my student days, about **30** years ago, I did the same: draw schematic, add net numbers, write a netlist by hand. That's because we didn't have a tool for drawing schematics. Since those days we have moved on. Pspice also has a schematic entry tool, explain why you're not using it.

Comment: Why do you assume that the delay is caused by an error in your netlist? Re-check your netlist. Then **think** about the mechanisms which could cause the delay. If you try the same simulation with at 10 Hz and 1 kHz now what do you see?

Comment: Please crop your screenshots before posting. Better yet, **export** the graphic as an image file.

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie ; sir i got the answer why the delay is occurring ;
i have edited my post accordingly, now only peak to peak variation error is coming....how to solve it,sir?

Comment: *i got the answer why the delay is occurring* No you didn't, at least I do not see an explanation in your text that C1 and R2 form a **highpass filter**. It is simply RC constants which cause delays. You're just **throwing formulas** at the circuit to get a solution but what you should do is ask yourself "How does this work?".